# expectation of uniformly distributed $n$ number of samples

Tags: probability, expectation, uniform-distribution

I am trying to fine the expectation:  $E((x_1+ x_2+ \cdots +x_n )^2)$  as a function of $n$ where all $x_1$ to $x_n$ have uniform distribution $U(0,1)$.

I can do if there is only $x_1$ and $x_2$ but what about for $n$ number of RVs? Any guideline?

Comment: Are the $X_i$ independent? Use the strategy you used for $X_1+X_2$, unless you found first the distribution of $X_1+X_2$, which for $n$ would be painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the square. We get $\sum_1^n X_i^2 +2\sum_{1\le i\lt j}X_iX_j$.

Now use the linearity of expectation, and independence. We get $nE(X_1^2)+(n)(n-1)E(X_1)E(X_1)$.

Comment: thanks André Nicolas! I thought about so many ways rather than just expanding! a big thanks! :D

Comment: You are welcome. The linearity of expectation (which holds even when the summands are not independent) is a powerful tool. It often lets us find the mean even when the distribution is hard to get a handle on.

Comment: actually, I am new to these probability and statistics stuff. Although I am trying to do as much as example possible to get a good grip over these. can u please tell me, cant we write $(n)(n−1)E(X1)E(X2)$ as $(n)(n-1)E(X1)^2$ as X are iid? also, it would be a great help, if u please explain how (n)(n-1) came. thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, each of the $X_i^2$ has the same distrbution, so each of the $X_i^2$ has the same mean, which is the mean of $X_1^2$, or of any $X^2$ where $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. As for the other, each $X_iX_j$ has (by independence) expectation $E(X_i)E(X_j)$, which is $E(X)E(X)$. I probably should not have said $E(X_1)E(X_2)$, though it is correct. Equally correct is $E(X_1)E(X_1)$, which I will edit to.

Comment: thank u. I want to know how, we can write, $(n)(n-1)$. i can see its obvious but cant find the steps.

Comment: Two ways: (i) There are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose a pair of distinct indices, and we had a $2$ in front, so we get $2\cdot \binom{n}{2}$, which is $2\cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$; (ii) or else when we multiply $X_1+\cdots +X_n$ by itself and open up the parentheses but don't do any simplification, we get $n^2$ raw terms. Of these, $n$ are of the form $X_i^2$ and the remaining $n^2-n$ are "mixed."

Comment: thats really great and helpful from you. thanks a lot. :D